# ERROR: function st_hexagongrid(integer, geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to run the following to test the `st_hexagongrid` function:

```
SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(10000, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 10, 11, 11, 4326), 3857))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_hexagongrid(integer, geometry) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(10000, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 9
```

I did check my `postgis` version and it is 3.2:

```
SELECT PostGIS_Version();

3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

Do you know any possible reasons for this issue?

Comment: your example works fine for me (automatically casting the size). Are other PostGIS functions working well? What do you get if you write `\df st_hexagongrid` in psql?

Comment: @JGH I am using server setup on Azure and not sure how to access psql. But I tried running this `select proname,prosrc from pg_proc where proname like 'ST_HexagonGrid'; ` and doesn't return any records.

Comment: the proname would be in lowercase

Comment: @JGH with the like statement it doesn't really matter, anyways I tried with lower case `select proname,prosrc from pg_proc where proname like 'st_hexagonGrid'; ` Same result...

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are passing as parameters an integer and a geometry, and the function requires a float and a geometry.

[**ST_HexagonGrid(float8 size, geometry bounds);**](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HexagonGrid.html)

change to:

```
SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(10000::numeric, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 10, 11, 11, 4326), 3857))
```

check this error:

*HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.*

is telling you that it couldn't find a function that has this name or the types of arguments passed. It also asks to try to pass the arguments explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the response but still get the error-  ERROR:  function st_hexagongrid(numeric, geometry) does not exist. LINE 2: SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(10000::numeric, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEn...

Comment: `integer` to `float8` is an implicit cast, see `pg_cast`